# manage and configure windows services with an own control panel

Tags: vb.net, windows-services, configurationmanager

I have written some windows services. Each service has some settings that I currently store in a .ini file.

I would like to manage the services now in a control panel and would like to be able to manage the settings there in a collective manner.

### Are the respective app.config files the right choice?

or should i store the settings (like timer Intervall, etc.) in the registry?

If not

### How to Access the app.config files?

I have tried something like that

```
Dim fileMap As ConfigurationFileMap = 
    New ConfigurationFileMap("myService.exe.config")
Dim configuration = 
    ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedMachineConfiguration(fileMap)
```

But the `AppSettings` are `Nothing`

or am I on the wrong track?

I hope somebody has a great idea

### how to manage and configure windows services with an own control panel?

Answer (score 1):

First of all: With the [ServiceController Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.aspx) you can control every Serivce (Start, Stop, Restart, and so on). You should check out the example at the MSDN page if you want to know how it works.

How you save your settings is your own choice. You could use the .config file, a .ini file or just the registry. Just choose the option which works better for you.

Since your services already use a .ini as a config file you could just access and edit these files with your control panel. I guess the .ini files are saved in the same folder where the service.exe is located. So you can use [AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.basedirectory.aspx) to find out where the service is located on the machine and start editing it. For your control panel you can also use a .ini config file our just play around with [My.Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/objects/my-settings-object)

Hope this brings you on the right track!